# How to trigger `dependent: destroy` when updating collection_singular_ids

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Consider the following setup:

```
class Task
  has_many :users, through: :task_users
end

class User
  has_many :tasks, through: :tasks_users
end

class TaskUser
  # Joins table
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end    

class Comment
  belongs_to :task_user
end
```

Now if I perform a standard `#destroy` command, such as:

```
tu = TaskUser.first
tu.destroy
```

Then all comments associated to the task-user will also be destroyed.

However, suppose you want to update a user's tasks via [`#collection_singular_ids=`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many), like so:

```
u = User.first
puts u.task_ids # => [1, 2, 3]
u.task_ids = [1, 2]
```

Doing this (without even calling `#save` explicitly!) will trigger `SQL` like:

```
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM `task_users` WHERE `task_users`.`task_id` = 3 AND `task_users`.`user_id` = 1 
(2.0ms)  COMMIT
```

...So the associated `Comment`s get orphaned.

The same issue occurs if you use `#attributes=`:

```
u.attributes = { task_ids: [1, 2] }
```

Is there a clean way to ensure that the associated `Comment`s will always be destroyed (i.e. never orphaned)?

Comment: MySQL's Innodb engine supports ON DELETE CASADE.. something to look into

Comment: Hmm yes, this is certainly an option... Although I'd rather not make this a database constraint, if possible. It would be better to have the *option* to `delete` vs `destroy`, and only trigger callbacks when desired.

Comment: @engineersmnky Possibly?? Can you provide a working example?

Comment: @TomLord it actually appears that you are misusing [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many) which clearly states *"The join table should not have a primary key or a model associated with it."* Since it has no anticipation of a model your callback does not fire. it would make more sense to have `Comments` belong to a `Task` and a `User` than to a `TaskUser` anyway

Comment: @engineersmnky Oh.. Yeah, sorry, I only wrote it like that in an attempt to keep my question as simple as possible. (I was trying to give a [mcve].) The real code is a bit more complex than this, and the models are named differently! I'll edit the above, but consider it to be as `has_many :through`.

Comment: Please don't mislead us with your question as it makes it more difficult to solve a problem that is different than the example. Have a look at `ActiveRecord::Associations::Callbacks#before_remove`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @engineersmnky for pointing me in the right direction.

This may not be the prettiest solution, but a viable option is to [define a callback *on the association*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), such as:

```
class User
  has_many :tasks,
    through: :tasks_users,
    before_remove: ->(user, task) do
      task_user = TaskUser.find_by!(user: user, task: task)
      task_user.comments.each(&:destroy!)
    end

  # Or alternatively, this can be defined as a method:

  has_many :tasks,
    through: :tasks_users,
    before_remove: :destroy_task_user_comments

  private

  def destroy_task_user_comments(task)
    task_user = TaskUser.find_by!(user: self, task: task)
    task_user.comments.each(&:destroy!)
  end
end
```

Note that I have used bang (`!`) methods within the block, so that the entire transaction will rollback if the an exception is raised - as per the documentation:

> if any of the `before_remove` callbacks throw an exception, the object will not be removed from the collection.